# Dark mode not showing up in Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-darkmode

I'm trying to adjust my colour scheme when enabling dark mode but it doesn't seem to work, not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have set an colour asset:

[image]

And then applied it to the background of my tableview cell:

[image]

But the outcome always just shows the "Light" appearance whenever I toggle dark mode - I've tried toggling through the app settings page, and also tried it on an actual device.

[image]

Can someone please advice what I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the issue - it was my info.plist which had "Appearance". I deleted this entry and now dark mode is working perfectly!